# Scrape table within a webpage?

Tags: php, jquery, dom, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I'm currently trying to scrape all the results from a table within a webpage. At the moment I'm attempting it with `file_get_contents()` and some jquery but I'm unable to seem to find the selectors within the `DOM` with jQuery.

I'm trying to get them row by row as I intend on inserting them into my database for future use.

My question is how would I get the values of each `<td>` within each `<tr>` within the table on the webpage in order to insert all of these values into my database?

PHP:

**Controller**

```
function scqf_stats(){

    $data['stats'] = file_get_contents("http://www.scqf.org.uk/Search%20The%20Database?ssub=&stit=Enter+a+title+or+a+part+of+it&sown=Start+typing+and+select+from+dropdown&sownid=&slev=&scrb=&sk=&submitsp=Search");
    $data['main_content'] = 'alt_test';

    $this->load->view('templates/single_view', $data);

}
```

**View**

```
<pre>

<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/scrape.js"></script>

<?php print_r($stats); ?>

</pre>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function scrape_it(){

    $('#search-database-results').children('tbody').children('tr').each(function (){
        $this = $(this);

        $('tr').children('td').each(function() {

            var text = $('td').text();
            console.log(text);

        });   

    });

}

scrape_it();

});
```

Comment: Where is the id search-database-results? is that the name of the table you are importing?

Comment: You need to show a sample of the HTML as you have "TR"s within "TR"s in your code (which can't be correct). i.e. `.children('tr').children('tr')`

Comment: `$('#search-database-results tr td').each(function(){...})` should be sufficient to find all TDs in all TRs in the `ID=search-database-results` element.

Comment: @Chitowns24 Yes the `search-database-results` is the id of the table

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie sorry that's meant to be `tbody` the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the scraped page in an element of `id=search-database-results` this should do to find all TDs within each TR within the table (in order):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scrape_it(){
        $('#search-database-results tr td').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            console.log(text);
        });
    }
    scrape_it();
});
```

If you need more/different, please explain in more detail.

Comment: The scraped page is not within `id="search-database-results"` but the table elements are within `<table id="search-database-results" class="tablesorter"></div>`

Comment: Just to confirm that this is also cross domain

Comment: It appears that the function `scrape_it()` just isn't firing at all

Comment: 1. So long as id="search-database-results" is above it it does not matter to the selector. 2. Cross domain page HTML requests may fail, so you may need to wrap it via your server. 3. Can you put a sample in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've just went and used `CURL` instead, does the same job. Thanks for your help